# Proving $\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1} x_i$ is odd

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Suppose n∈N and that $x_1...x_{2n+1}$ are odd integers. Prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1} x_i$$ is odd

Base Case: $x_1$ is odd, the base case holds true

I.H: Suppose it's true for

$\sum_{i=1}^{2k+1} (x_i)$ , k is odd

How do i do the induction step to prove its odd?

Comment: you dont need to use the parenthesis in $(x_i)$. Induction is based in three steps: base case, induction hypothesis and induction step, where are you stuck?

Comment: @Masacroso can u check my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hypothesis is that your statement holds for $2k+1$ for some $k$, now you want to show that this hypothesis imply that the statement also holds for $k+1$, that is: you want to show that if $\sum_{j=1}^{2k+1}x_j$ is odd (our hypothesis) then $\sum_{j=1}^{2(k+1)+1}x_j$ is also odd (the induction step), where every $x_j$ is odd.

Because $2(k+1)+1=2k+3$ then the change from the hypothesis is the addition of two odd integers. The sum of two odd integers is even, and the sum of an even and an odd is odd.$\Box$

Comment: why I was downvoted? Lol.

Answer (score 0):

a few arithmetic facts, odd+odd=even; even+odd=odd   so when we sum the first two, we get an even number. that even number plus the next odd number will produce an odd number. these two facts together show that an odd number of odd numbers summed together is an odd number. 2n+1 is odd therefore, there are an odd number of odd numbers in the sum we want. So, the sum is odd.